# Marker.remove(), Marker.setPosition not working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, geofire

Hi so I am using Geofire and Whenever an object in my query range I am trying to show it on the users map using markers and updating the markers position in realtime.

I initialize the marker in the geofire onkeyentered method and then when the location of the key changed (so onkeymoved is called), I change the location of the marker using marker.setposition. However, the marker creates a copy of it at the original location, and then moves (creating 2 markers, even though I only used setPosition)

Here is the code for the geofire listeners:

```
geoQueryP.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                            LatLng drivLoc = new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
                            createDriverMarker(key, drivLoc, reference);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onKeyExited(String key) {
                            if(markerPoints.get(key) != null) {
                                markerPoints.get(key).remove();
                                markerPoints.remove(key);
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                            if(markerPoints.get(key) != null) {
                                markerPoints.get(key).setPosition(new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude));
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error + " Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Here is the code for the createDriverMarker method:

```
private void createDriverMarker(String key, LatLng drivLocation, String reference) {
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    locationRelatedFunctions bitmap = new locationRelatedFunctions();
    markerOptions.position(drivLocation)
            .title(reference)
            .icon((bitmap.bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_radio_button_checked_black_24dp)));
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    markerPoints.put(key, marker);
}
```

MarkerPoints is a hashmap, initialized like:

```
    public HashMap<String, Marker> markerPoints;
```

then in the onCreate:

```
        markerPoints = new HashMap<String, Marker>();
```

Comment: Ok! Then you have a logic error in your code. I will take a look if I can find it. I will removed my original answer as it is not a help to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suspect the `onKeyEntered` is being called more than expected - but can be remedied:

```
public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
    LatLng drivLoc = new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
    if (!markerPoints.containsKey(key)) {
        createDriverMarker(key, drivLoc, reference);
    } else {
       // this part is optional given that the 'moved' event may have
       // triggered first...
       onKeyMoved(key,location);
    }
}
```

You may want to add debug to confirm the extra onKeyEntered invocations.

One flaw in your OP code is along the same lines - IF the onKeyEntered is invoked twice for the same key you'll end up with 2 markers - one unmanaged since the second 'put' of the same key overwrites the first one but leaves the original marker on the map.  In principle, your code should work - but you should still guard against unexpected event sequences.

A more complete analysis would require you posting how you update GeoFire with position updates.

Comment: Yup this works! Thanks so much, although it does raise the question of why onkeyentered was being triggered twice.